Blocking OpenAI Requests
After multiple attempts at this myself along with numerous ChatGPT and Claude queries, I am throwing my hands up and asking StackOverflow what would seem to be an easy question:
How does one block OpenAI, at the global level, from making HTTP requests when testing using pytest?
Things I have tried (and this list is likely forgetting many):

Use httpx-blockage
In conftest.py add in a patch for OpenAI:

@pytest.fixture(autouse=True)
def block_azure_openai():
    with patch.object(AzureOpenAI, '__init__', return_value=None):
        yield


In conftest.py patch OpenAI and the utility function that returns an instance of the OpenAI client:

@pytest.fixture(autouse=True)
def block_httpx(monkeypatch):
    with patch('ai.utils.get_openai_client', return_value=Mock()), patch('ai.utils.AzureOpenAI', return_value=None):
        yield


Patch the AsyncClient

@pytest.fixture(scope='session')
async def block_httpx(monkeypatch):
    async def mock_httpx_request(*args, **kwargs):
        raise RuntimeError("HTTPx requests are blocked during tests")

    monkeypatch.setattr(httpx.AsyncClient, "request", mock_httpx_request)
    # Add more if needed for other methods like .get, .post, etc.


Patch the Client

@pytest.fixture(scope='session')
def block_httpx(monkeypatch):
    def mock_httpx_request(*args, **kwargs):
        raise RuntimeError("HTTPx requests are blocked during tests")

    with patch('httpcore'):
        monkeypatch.setattr(httpx.Client, "request", mock_httpx_request)
        yield

None of these have worked and while running tests I continue to see, in Azure's metrics, requests coming in .

The only idea I have remaining is to quit this job so the user story can be someone else's problem. Hoping someone here has one better than that though 

The big hammer is to run your unit tests in a network namespace that doesn't have any routes/interfaces/etc defined. Very similarly, one can use OS-level measures to block traffic out except through a filtering proxy that applies whatever rules you choose.

I've never worked with Azure, but... is it possible to instrument your code, with print statements if nothing else, and check whether your patches are getting triggered? Or, as @CharlesDuffy suggests, firewall off the relevant outgoing connection and see if you can see an error origin?

I suppose I could take the big hammer approach, although I'd rather avoid it and keep to the existing pattern we have of blocking HTTP requests (all of our other API requests are blocked by http-blockage just fine). At the very least it could be a place to start that might reveal something useful.
You would think I would have tried some simple print statements after all of this....but nope, actually hadn't ‍♀️ So yeah, step one - see if these mocks even run. Step 2: Big hammer it and just block the requests, maybe I can get a modification of etc/hosts in my conftest

I only suggested the big hammer as the means to trigger an exception so you can see where the request is happening, and find out whether you are applying the tiny hammer at the correct spot. :D
